# Should I leave the fan switch on my thermostat set to fan rather than auto?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace

I purchased a new Amanda Furnace in Oct'2013. I am told in order to maximize a warm, consistent room temperature I should set the thermostat to the Fan position rather than the Auto position.  Does this make a difference in maintaining room temperature and is it more costly?

Answer (score 1):

Running the air handler all the time is generally going to cost you some significant electricity. Since either is fine, try it both ways and see what you think, in your house; houses do vary.

Answer (score 0):

While it is impossible to give you a quantitative answer without knowing more details about your house and system (e.g. how they set the fan speed in each setting) in my opinion it is better to have the system on Fan setting.

What it does is running the blower motor even when heat/AC is not actively heating cooling. While running the fan does consume electricity, you end up with a more uniform air throughout the house.

Answer (score 0):

It will cost you more in electricity and in filters. Running the fans is basically recirculating the air throughout your house. It will possibly make it colder depending on where the draws are located. If they are downstairs it will more likely push the cold air from downstairs upstairs (given the fact that hot air rises). In the summer it is smarter because you are evenly distributing the air upward.